# Determine column data with if condition in a joined tables SQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a query that works well, where i would like an assistance is how to incorporate a condition to determine the value displayed on a given column. That is if a column of a table has a value say "Authorization of COA" then the column date added should show the date else the column should show null

Here is my query so far

```
SELECT r.request_id, r.product_name, r.created_at, r.can,a_s.stat, r.client_id, CONCAT(u.fname,' ',u.lname) 'analyst' , t.date_added (//should show the value of date_added else NULL based on a condition for this column),
    FROM request r
    LEFT OUTER JOIN assigned_samples a_s ON r.request_id = a_s.labref
    LEFT OUTER JOIN user u ON a_s.analyst_id = u.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tracking_table t ON r.request_id = t.labref
    WHERE r.client_id='$cid'
    AND r.created_at BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end'
    AND a_s.department_id = '$dept'
    GROUP BY r.request_id
    ORDER BY `r`.`created_at` DESC "
```

Comment: Either tag all the RDBMSs you know or keep just one :)

Comment: In mysql use if() function or case expression, in ms sql use case expression.

Answer (score 1):

A simple CASE statement should be sufficient in this case, I believe.

```
SELECT r.request_id, r.product_name, r.created_at, r.can,a_s.stat, r.client_id, 
CONCAT(u.fname,' ',u.lname) 'analyst', 
CASE WHEN ConditionColumn = 'Authorization of COA' THEN t.date_added 
ELSE NULL END AS 'date_added' 
    FROM request r
    LEFT OUTER JOIN assigned_samples a_s ON r.request_id = a_s.labref
    LEFT OUTER JOIN user u ON a_s.analyst_id = u.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tracking_table t ON r.request_id = t.labref
    WHERE r.client_id='$cid'
```

Answer (score 0):

In both mysql and ms sql you can use case expression ([mysql case](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case); [ms sql case](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms181765.aspx)) to assign value to a field conditionally:

```
SELECT r.request_id, r.product_name, r.created_at, r.can,a_s.stat, r.client_id, CONCAT(u.fname,' ',u.lname) 'analyst' , 
    CASE WHEN Column_To_Test = 'Authorization of COA' THEN t.date_added
        ELSE null
    END AS date_added 
    FROM request r
    LEFT OUTER JOIN assigned_samples a_s ON r.request_id = a_s.labref
    LEFT OUTER JOIN user u ON a_s.analyst_id = u.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tracking_table t ON r.request_id = t.labref
    WHERE r.client_id='$cid'
    AND r.created_at BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end'
    AND a_s.department_id = '$dept'
    GROUP BY r.request_id
    ORDER BY `r`.`created_at` DESC "
```

This way the solution is more portable between the databases. Mysql offers if() function, ms sql iif() to achieve the above, but those are product specific solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the Case statements like.

> **CASE WHEN** ( *Condition_1* AND *Condition_2* OR ... *Condition_N*)  **THEN** (Value_1) **ELSE** (Value_1) **END**

Here **Condition**_1 can be column record value and its combination of Column record values
and **Value**_1 can be single value [Ex: Null or "some string"] or Returned value from nested sql statement like [Ex: (select count(*) from ...)]

Answer (score -1):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT r.request_id, r.product_name, r.created_at, r.can,a_s.stat, r.client_id, CONCAT(u.fname,' ',u.lname) 'analyst' , 
IFF(nameOfColumnToTest = 'Authorization of COA', t.date_added, null) AS DateAdded 
    FROM request r
    LEFT OUTER JOIN assigned_samples a_s ON r.request_id = a_s.labref
    LEFT OUTER JOIN user u ON a_s.analyst_id = u.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tracking_table t ON r.request_id = t.labref
    WHERE r.client_id='$cid'
    AND r.created_at BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end'
    AND a_s.department_id = '$dept'
    GROUP BY r.request_id
    ORDER BY `r`.`created_at` DESC "
```